# php encrypt and decrypt number string with key

Tags: php, encryption

a lot of questions have been asked and answered about this subject but none of the answers have helped me.

I am looking for a php function that will encrypt a small integer like this:

`123456` into  an encrypted string with only `A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`

so the output would look like `a1b2c3d4`.

and I would be able to use a key like `stringkey` to be able to convert it back to `123456`

---

any help?

Comment: You can use basically every encryption algorithm, that PHP/mcrypt provides with an appropriate encoding. Is there any constraint on the output size?

Comment: I don't need/want it to be very long. 8 characters max probably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$key = "encryption key";
$text="123456";
$encrypted = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($text,'AES-128-CBC', $key));
$decrypted=openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($encrypted),'AES-128-CBC',$key);
var_dump($encrypted,$decrypted);
```

strictly speaking though, this will only be a-f and 0-9, you can come up with a better (more compact) algorithm supporting a-zA-Z... nothing comes to my mind right now thought. (suggestions anyone?)

Comment: a-z works fine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The upcoming version 2.0.0 of [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) is going to, by default, encode its output as hexadecimal characters.

```
<?php
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;

$key = Crypto::createNewRandomKey();

$encrypted = Crypto::encrypt('123456', $key); // hex encoded
$raw_bytes = Crypto::encrypt('123456', $key, true); // raw binary
```

Note that Defuse's PHP library provides [authenticated encryption](http://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken), not just plain encryption. You should make certain you understand [the difference between encryption and authentication](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).

> I don't need/want it to be very long. 8 characters max probably.

This sounds like a mistake, and that mistake has a name: [hashids](http://hashids.org).

If you're trying to obfsucate, say, a row ID, you don't want to encrypt it. Instead, generate a random string and store it as another column in the same table. Adding a column to your database schema is cheap, and randomly generating it is far safer than deriving it deterministically from an integer.

That's what we do for [our audit reports](https://paragonie.com/security), to not leak the sequence number.